Word document with two inserted excel spreadsheets, cross referencing cells between them
I have a word document in which I have inserted two separate excel spreadsheets using the Insert tab, then Table button, then Excel Spreadsheet in the drop down menu in Word. Let's call them sheet1 and sheet2.


I have text data in sheet1 that I would like to have inserted into sheet2 automatically. Specifically what I am trying to do, is get the name of a company that is entered into a cell in sheet1, to also be entered into sheet2 upon entering it into sheet1. This same method of referencing would be useful calculations with data from another excel spreadsheet which is inserted into the word document.
If that isn't possible, can one inserted excel spreadsheet be placed at multiple locations in a word file? If so, I could create additional sheets in the one excel spreadsheet which can be easily referenced between.

What research have you done regarding getting data from an Excel table into a Word document?

that can be done using VBA

I wouldn't put effort into trying to make this work. AFAIK the kind of cross-object linking you would like to do is not possible in modern versions of Word using the UI. Here I do not get the option even to paste a link in sheet2. More was possible, but not reliable, in, say, Word 2000! If you create an Excel file externally, you might be able to make multiple links to the sheets and/or specific cells, but lots of Excel links take time to update. Probably better to maintain your Excel sheet separately and use VBA to access Excel data and copy it into your Word doc.
